# Hiding or showing menu item in asp.net based on whether user is logged in or not

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to make a change to a website's menu system which is written in asp.net and vb.net.  I would like to hide the menu item (Value="ProdinTran") from being seen when a user is not logged into the site.  Can you show me what I need to add to this code to do this?

Here is the current code:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Site.Master.vb" Inherits="Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                     Portal
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" />&nbsp;</span>!&nbsp; 
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" DisappearAfter="1000">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home">
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Portal Home Page" 
                                Value="Portal Home Page"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://www.something.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=212&Itemid=28" Text="About" 
                                Value="About" Target="_parent"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://www.something.com" 
                                Text="Web Site" 
                                ToolTip="Home Page" Value="Home" Target="_parent">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                       <asp:MenuItem Text="Customer" Value="Customer" 
                            ToolTip="Registered customers" NavigateUrl="~/Customer.aspx?mySelect=0">
                             <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Customer.aspx?mySelect=0"
                                Text="Customer Home Page" Value="Chp">
                             </asp:MenuItem>
                             <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Customer.aspx?mySelect=2" 
                                Text="Open Orders" 
                                ToolTip="View your open orders" Value="OpenOrders">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                              <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Customer.aspx?mySelect=3" 
                                Text="Canceled Orders" 
                                ToolTip="View your canceled orders" Value="Canceled">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Customer.aspx?mySelect=4" 
                                Text="Shipped Orders" 
                                ToolTip="View your shipped orders" Value="Shipped">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Product in Transit" ToolTip="Product in Transit" Value="ProdinTran" NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Customer.aspx?mySelect=5" 
                                Text="Invoices" 
                                ToolTip="View your invoices" Value="Invoices">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Customer.aspx?mySelect=6" 
                                Text="Credit Memos" 
                                ToolTip="View your credit memos" Value="Credits">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Account/ChangePassword.aspx" 
                                Text="Change Password" ToolTip="Change your password." 
                                Value="Change">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                      </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Help &amp; Information" 
                            ToolTip="Holidays, Shipping, Passwords" Value="Help">
                             <asp:MenuItem Text="Terms &amp; Conditions" 
                                ToolTip="View Terms &amp; Conditions" 
                                Value="Terms" NavigateUrl="http://www.something.com/terms.html" 
                                 Target="_parent">
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                           <asp:MenuItem Text="Holiday Schedule" 
                                ToolTip="View Holiday Schedule" 
                                Value="Holiday" NavigateUrl="~/Holiday.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Shipping Company Information" 
                                ToolTip="View information on shipping companies" 
                                Value="Shipping" NavigateUrl="~/Shipping.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Forgot.aspx" Text="Reset My Password" 
                                ToolTip="Reset your password." Value="Reset">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/HowDoI.aspx" Text="How Do I Access my info?" 
                                ToolTip="See how to register, logon, reset your password, change your password and access your account." Value="Retrieve">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Register                " 
                                ToolTip="Click here to register on this site" 
                                Value="Register2" NavigateUrl="~/Account/Register.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Remnant1.aspx" Text="Remnants" 
                                Value="Remnants"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
 &copy;&nbsp;2014 - All Rights Reserved<br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB.NET placed in Site.master.vb:

```
Partial Class Site
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            NavigationMenu.FindItem("Customer").ChildItems.Remove(NavigationMenu.FindItem("Customer,ProdinTran"))
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension method to find Menu Item by value.

C#

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
        public static System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItem GetMenuItemByValue(this System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu menu, string ItemValue)
            {
            foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItem item in menu.Items)
                {
                if (item.Value == ItemValue)
                    {
                    return item;
                    }
                }
            return null;
            }
   }
```

VB.NET

```
Public NotInheritable Class ExtensionMethods
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Shared Function GetMenuItemByValue(menu As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu, ItemValue As String) As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItem
        For Each item As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItem In menu.Items
            If item.Value = ItemValue Then
                Return item
            End If
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

So then I could do something like..

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!User.IsAuthenticated)
    {
       NavigationMenu.GetMenuItemByValue("ProdinTran").Visible=false;;
    }
}
```

VB.NET

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Not User.IsAuthenticated Then
        NavigationMenu.GetMenuItemByValue("ProdinTran").Visible = False       
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I like how clean and neat your example is.  I am not a developer and I am just fixing someone else's code, so how would I incorporate this into my code?

Comment: Put the ExtensionMethods class into a new ExtensionsMethods.cs file in the App_Code folder. The other code will go in the Page_Load function for the codebehind (Site.Master.vb) file that goes with the menu. You may have to create those if they don't already exist. Note that this does **not** prevent the user from manually navigating to the NavigateUrl of the menu item. It just makes the menu item not visible.

Comment: Oh, you know I just realized you tagged this as VB.NET. I wrote my code in C# so you'll have to ask someone to translate it (I don't know VB.NET).

Comment: @Kevin I used a tool to convert to VB.NET from C#. I edited my answer to include the code. I can't vouch for the accuracy since I don't know VB, but it looks good to me. The tool was http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: If getting an error. BC30451: 'User' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.  Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you have added a using statement (or whatever the equivalent is in VB) for the System.Web.UI namespace. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: We just hired a new web dev. and she was able to assist me.  I will post as the answer what we did.  Thank you for your help.